# Laravel 7 Get data using Auth::user() method

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have made a custom login using `Auth::attemp` to check the data in db.

It returns true, so I can `redirecto` to user profile.

However, in this view I'm trying to get username using `Auth::user()->username` *(username is the column in db)* but I get the following error:

> [image: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object]

Here's my login function:

```
    public function login()
{
    request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = array(
        "email" => request("email"),
        "password" => request("password")
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::route('user.profile');
    }

    return Redirect::route('user.showLoginForm');

}
```

And here's my profile view:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>
                        Registro
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        Este es el perfil de {{ Auth::user()->username }}

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my users'table migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->string('username', 50);
    $table->string('email', 150);
    $table->string('PASSWORD', 500);
    $table->string('profileImage', 500)->default(null);
    $table->boolean('admin')->default('0');
    $table->time('created_At')->nullable()->useCurrent();
    $table->increments('ID');

    $table->unique('id', 'id');

});
```

I checked and `Auth::user()->username` return the expected value, so I don't know what happened.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your user table has username?can you send you migration for user table?

Comment: What's yours users table structure? Do you have username field there?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

```
if you try {{dd(auth()->user())}} and you get null , you should add auth middleware 
 for your route and you will see.
```

Comment: I get the following error: Route [login] not defined. I added auth middleware to profile route like this: 

Route::get("/perfil", "UserController@showProfile")->name('user.profile')->middleware("auth");

Answer (score 0):

if you changed the login route you have also to change route in your auth middleware

Comment: How can I change it?